# Draw curved text

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

They know if there is any library or method in Delphi (Firemonkey) to write curved text or following a path of coordinates?. This would be a very interesting way to accompany text around geometric figures. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913550/how-do-i-render-text-along-an-arc-in-an-image

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the graphic system of the VCL is very different from Firemonkey. In any case, while I answered I have seen the following link https://github.com/zhaoyipeng/graphics32-for-Firemonkey/tree/master/Source -, It will be interesting then to see what level of portability has been achieved from this library.

Comment: you must do it directly using the android os api / ios os api. it's will be not very hard